# pass list of sObject from one queueable job to another

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger, queueable-interface

I am trying to pass Sobject from trigger to a queueable and then i am calling another queueable and trying to pass the same sObject. But i am unable to get the values in queueable .

Trigger -

```
trigger checkaccount on contact (after insert, after update) {
    List<Contact> cont = new List<Contact>();
    for(Contact record: Trigger.new) {
        cont.add(record);
    }
    System.enqueueJob(new firstqueablejob (cont)); 
}
```

firstqueablejob

```
public class firstqueablejob implements Queueable,Database.AllowsCallouts {

    List<Contact> cont = new List<Contact>();
    public firstqueablejob (List<Contact> cont) {
        cont = cont;
    }
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) { 
        system.debug('contfirst ' + cont); // I am getting null here
        System.enqueueJob(new secondqueuablejob (cont)); 
    }
}
```

secondqueuablejob

```
public class secondqueuablejob implements Queueable,Database.AllowsCallouts {

     List<Contact> cont = new List<Contact>();
    public secondqueuablejob (List<Contact> cont) {
        cont = cont;
    }
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) { 
        system.debug('contsecond' + cont); // I am getting null here
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please try by changing the statement `cont=cont` to `this.cont=cont` at both queueables.

Answer (score 4):

Simple mistake here; you named the member variable and the parameter the same name. This causes a "shadow" effect. To assign the value to the member variable, use `this`.

```
public secondqueuablejob (List<Contact> cont) {
    this.cont = cont;
}
```

P.S. Instead of looping over all the elements, you could have just called List.deepClone...

```
System.enqueueJob(new firstqueablejob (Trigger.new.deepClone(true,true,true)));
```

Or even just List.clone:

```
System.enqueueJob(new firstqueablejob (Trigger.new.clone()));
```

Or just pass in Trigger.new directly (that's perfectly legal!):

```
System.enqueueJob(new firstqueablejob (Trigger.new));
```